# display table row only when if statement is correct

Tags: php, html

I want to display table row with its content only if the two variables are not empty but it seems the syntax is not correct. Could you please have a look at my code.

```
<?php                  
  if (!empty($title1) && !empty($title2)) {

    echo '
  <tr>
    <td>
    <b>Title 1: </b><br>'.$title1; 
    if (!empty($more_one)) { 
      echo '<br><a href="'.$more_one.'" >See More</a>';
    }    
     echo  
    '</td>
    <td>
    <b>Title 2: </b><br>'.$title2; 
    if (!empty($more_two)) { 
      echo '<br><a href="'.$more_two.'" >See More</a>';
    }    
     echo   
    '</td>    
  </tr>'
}
```

?>

Comment: you are missing an echo after first closing braces

Comment: ie `if (!empty($more_one)) { 
  echo '<br><a href="'.$more_one.'" >See More</a>';
}    
  echo  '</td>
    <td>
    <b>Title 2: </b><br>'.$title2; `

Comment: similarly after the second closing braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$title1%20=%20%22foo%22;%20$title2%20=%20%22bar%22;%5Cnif%20(!empty($title1)%20%2526%2526%20!empty($title2)):%5Cn?%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3E%5Cn%20%3C?php%5Cn%20echo%20%27%3Cb%3ETitle%201:%20%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%3E%27%20.%20$title1;%5Cn%20if%20(!empty($more_one))%20echo%20%27%3Cbr%3E%3Ca%20href=%22%27.$more_one.%27%22%20%3ESee%20More%3C/a%3E%27;%5Cn%20?%3E%5Cn%5Cn%20%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3E%5Cn%20%3C?php%5Cn%20echo%20%27%3Cb%3ETitle%202:%20%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%3E%27.$title2;%5Cn%20if%20(!empty($more_two))%20echo%20%27%3Cbr%3E%3Ca%20href=%22%27.$more_two.%27%22%20%3ESee%20More%3C/a%3E%27;%5Cn%20?%3E%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%20%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E%5Cn%3C?php%20endif;%20?%3E)

```
<?php    
$title1 = "foo"; $title2 = "bar";
if (!empty($title1) && !empty($title2)):
?>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <?php 
   echo '<b>Title 1: </b><br>' .  $title1; 
   if (!empty($more_one)) echo '<br><a href="'.$more_one.'" >See More</a>'; 
  ?>  

  </td>
  <td>
  <?php 
   echo '<b>Title 2: </b><br>'.$title2; 
   if (!empty($more_two)) echo '<br><a href="'.$more_two.'" >See More</a>';
  ?>


  </td>    
  </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's that endif in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code as follows

```
<?php                  
  if (!empty($title1) && !empty($title2)) {
    echo '<tr><td><b>Title 1: </b><br>'.$title1; 
    if (!empty($more_one)) { 
      echo '<br><a href="'.$more_one.'" >See More</a>';
    }    
    echo '</td><td><b>Title 2: </b><br>'.$title2; 
    if (!empty($more_two)) { 
      echo '<br><a href="'.$more_two.'" >See More</a>';
    }    
    echo '</td>  </tr>';
  }   
?>
```

there was many `echo`s missing in your code..

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you to take care of your conditions

```
<?php

if (!empty($title1) && !empty($title2)) {
    $html = "";
    $html .='<tr><td><b>Title 1: </b><br>' . $title1;
    if (!empty($more_one)) {
        $html .= '<br><a href="' . $more_one . '" >See More</a>';
    }

    $html .= '</td><td><b>Title 2: </b><br>' . $title2;
    if (!empty($more_two)) {
        $html .= '<br><a href="' . $more_two . '" >See More</a>';
    }

    $html .= '</td> </tr>';

    echo $html;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
while(!empty($title1) && !empty($title2)){
//Do this
}
```

replace the result loader for the query inside the while param.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                  
  if ($title1 != '' && $title2 != '') {
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>
            <b>Title 1: </b><br>'.$title1; 
            if ($more_one != '') { 
                echo '<br><a href="'.$more_one.'" >See More</a>';
            }    
            echo  
            '</td>
            <td>
            <b>Title 2: </b><br>'.$title2; 
            if ($more_two != '') { 
                echo '<br><a href="'.$more_two.'" >See More</a>';
            }    
            echo   
            '</td>    
       </tr>';
   } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

on last echo missing ";"

```
echo '</td> </tr>';
```